# verify that there is at least one yellow cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that copies the colored cells from dynamic Table to another Table.
What I want to do is verify that there is at least one red or yellow colored cell before copying cells.

[image: verify in this tab]

If there is at least one red cell then copy the red cell in tab 1 else don't copy any cell and go to check for yellow cells.

If there is at least one yellow cell then copy yellow cell in Tab 2 else exit sub and display message "no colored cells"

[image: tab 1 and tab 2 after copying]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code and change the destination cell to paste values

```
Sub color()
Dim cll As Range
For Each cll In Selection
    If cll.Interior.color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
        cll.Copy
        Sheets(2).Range("Destinationcell").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Else
        If cll.Interior.color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
            cll.Copy
            Sheets(2).Range("Destinationcell").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Else
            MsgBox ("No Colored Cell")
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

You can use the following code as well

```
Sub color()
    Dim cll As Range, i as integer, j as integer
    For Each cll In Selection
        If cll.Interior.color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then i=i+1
        Else
          If cll.Interior.color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then j= j +1
          Else
             MsgBox ("No Colored Cell")
          End If
        End IF
        if i>=1 Then
          cll.Copy
          Sheets(2).Range("Destinationcell").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End if
        if j>=1 then
          cll.copy
          Sheets(2).Range("Destinationcell").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End if

    Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Notes: this works only if (1) the "red" you are using is the one that H.hisoka used to color his/her cells. Of course, the same applies to the "yellow" he/she is using. (2) If H.hisoka uses conditional formatting to color the cells then your solution will not work either.

Comment: This code can work to any color, provided the RGB selection is checked and formatted in the above code accordingly

Comment: thank you for your response, but that's not what I meant. , I have a complex code and the example that I poster was a simplification, the code can copy like you said, what I want is to tell it that before executing the copying part of code he have to be sure that there is at least one yellow cell in TAB

Comment: if there is at least one yellow cell the second part of the code can be executed and if there is not the code have to say that there is not yellow cell in the tab ,  exit from the code with out executing the second part of the code

Comment: I have added another answer, as per your requirement

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following powerful FindAll function below to search for formatted cells and then process the results...

For eg.

```
Sub FindColours()

    Dim FoundRange As Range

    Application.FindFormat.Clear
    Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Set FoundRange = FindAll("", SearchFormat:=True)
    If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then
        ' Do Red Cell Stuff
        MsgBox FoundRange.Address
    End If

    Application.FindFormat.Clear
    Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    Set FoundRange = FindAll("", SearchFormat:=True)
    If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then
        ' Do Yellow Cell Stuff
        MsgBox FoundRange.Address
    End If
End Sub

Function FindAll(What, _
    Optional SearchWhat As Variant, _
    Optional LookIn, _
    Optional LookAt, _
    Optional SearchOrder, _
    Optional SearchDirection As XlSearchDirection = xlNext, _
    Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False, _
    Optional MatchByte, _
    Optional SearchFormat) As Range

    'LookIn can be xlValues or xlFormulas, _
     LookAt can be xlWhole or xlPart, _
     SearchOrder can be xlByRows or xlByColumns, _
     SearchDirection can be xlNext, xlPrevious, _
     MatchCase, MatchByte, and SearchFormat can be True or False. _
     Before using SearchFormat = True, specify the appropriate settings for the Application.FindFormat _
     object; e.g. Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "General;-General;""-"""

    Dim SrcRange As Range
    If IsMissing(SearchWhat) Then
        Set SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    ElseIf TypeOf SearchWhat Is Range Then
        Set SrcRange = IIf(SearchWhat.Cells.Count = 1, SearchWhat.Parent.UsedRange, SearchWhat)
    ElseIf TypeOf SearchWhat Is Worksheet Then
        Set SrcRange = SearchWhat.UsedRange
    Else: SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    End If
    If SrcRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    'get the first matching cell in the range first
    With SrcRange.Areas(SrcRange.Areas.Count)
        Dim FirstCell As Range: Set FirstCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
    End With

    Dim CurrRange As Range: Set CurrRange = SrcRange.Find(What:=What, After:=FirstCell, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, _
        SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)

    If Not CurrRange Is Nothing Then
        Set FindAll = CurrRange
        Do
            Set CurrRange = SrcRange.Find(What:=What, After:=CurrRange, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, _
            SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)
            If CurrRange Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            If Application.Intersect(FindAll, CurrRange) Is Nothing Then
                Set FindAll = Application.Union(FindAll, CurrRange)
            Else: Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Function
```